# Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

This code has been working fine for years.

```
public PageReference chkinst() {
        i=0;
        integer j=0;

        Set<String> aSearchSet = new Set<String>();
        List<Lead> lList = ui;
        for (Lead l : lList) {
           aSearchSet.add(l.company);              
        }

        Account[] accountToCreate = new Account[]{};
        Map<String,Account> companyToAccountMap = new Map<String,Account> ();
        for (Account a: [select id, Name from Account where name IN :aSearchSet])
        companyToAccountMap.put(a.name,a);


        for (Lead l : lList) {
            if (!companyToAccountMap.containsKey(l.company)){
                Account act = new Account(Name = l.Company , Country__c = l.Country__c );
                accountToCreate.add(act);
                j = j +1;
            }    
        }

        insert accountToCreate;

        if(j == 0) {
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'All leads have correct institution names'));
        } else{
              ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,j + ' Institutions created')); 
        }

            return null;
}
```

Today, it gave me the following error:

Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 135.078KB

Does anyone know why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from this code snippet.  But if I had to guess.  It looks like your companyToAccountMap is a class level variable, and it's probably returning more records now then it used to.  If you don't need that map anywhere else in the controller, I would move it to a method level or make it transient.